# Partial fraction decomposition of $\frac4{x^2(x^2+7)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac4{x^2(x^2+7)}$$
I am not sure how to start the process; would I begin by placing 4 over $x^2$ and 4 over $x^2+7$? please help by listing steps and answering if possible.

Comment: How about doing $$\frac4{x(x+7)}$$ first?

Comment: Write $$\frac{4}{x^2(x^2+7)}=\dfrac{A}{x^2}+\dfrac{B}{x}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+7}$$
and find $A,B,C,D$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac4{x^2(x^2+7)}=\frac{4}{7}\frac{(x^2+7)-x^2}{x^2(x^2+7)}$$

Comment: I am not sure if this is a Partial Fraction Decomposition

Comment: @TylorGonzalez Just fill-in the last step $(a-b)/ab=1/b-1/a$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing the formula

$$\frac{4}{x^{2}\left( x^{2}+7\right) }=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^{2}}+\frac{Cx+D%
}{x^{2}+7}$$

Multiply each side by $x^{2}\left( x^{2}+7\right)$

$$4=Ax\left( x^{2}+7\right) +B\left( x^{2}+7\right) +\left( Cx+D\right) x^{2}$$

Equivalently,

$$4=\left( A+C\right) x^{3}+\left( B+D\right) x^{2}+7Ax+7B$$

Equating coefficients gives $A=0,B=\frac{4}{7},C=0,D=-\frac{4}{7}$

Substituting these back into the formula

$$\frac{4}{x^{2}\left( x^{2}+7\right) }=\frac{4}{7x^{2}}-\frac{4}{7\left(
x^{2}+7\right) }$$